# Getting image url from json object not working

Tags: php, json, object

I am trying to decode a json object so I can get an image url from it. Usually this works fine, but somehow the following code is not working for me.

```
$partimages1 = $prods['images'];
$partsimg1 = json_decode($partsimages1);

if($partsimg1->image_intro != ''){
  $productimages = '<img class="kw-prodimage-img" src="cms/'.$partsimg1->image_intro.'" alt="Product 1" title="Product 1" />';
}else{
  $productimages = '<img class="kw-prodimage-img" src="images/backgroundheader.jpg" alt="Product 1" title="Product 1" />';
}
```

The above code always returns backgroundheader.jpg while there is an image inside the object.

When I echo $partimages1 this is the result:

```
{"image_intro":"images\/Afbeeldingen\/lassen2.jpg","float_intro":"","image_intro_alt":"","image_intro_caption":"","image_fulltext":"","float_fulltext":"","image_fulltext_alt":"","image_fulltext_caption":""}
```

What is going wrong?

Comment: Turn up your error reporting. You would have seen the issue immediately. `error_reporting = E_ALL`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have a typo change `$partsimages1` to `$partimages1`

```
$partsimg1 = json_decode($partimage1);
```

Comment: Sometimes takes a fresh eye to notice such a stupid mistake.. Thanks!